# What way should I use to load a file from a module?

Tags: 7

What way should I use to load a file from a module?

I am writing a module which is divided into 3 parts

- Custom core will be in the module which contains basic functions required for project
- Custom notification section will handle the notifications to show on site (It has a section on site where user can see all notifications.)
- Custom mail will handle mail (Users will get email on each activity.)

So I have now a module file and 2 include files, but I am confused on how to include them in .module file.

There are 3 different methods available, but I am not sure which one is best and what the major differences between them are.

1. `require_once drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module')`
2. `files[] = mail.inc`
3. `module_load_include('inc', 'custom_module', 'mail.inc')`

I tried them, and they all are working fine for now; I don't have much experience to guess future issues.

Comment: You can include by using `function module_load_include`

Comment: yes i can use it but why it is best ?

Answer (score 2):

`module_load_include()` is a wrapper around `require_once`, with some sugar, so those are essentially equivalent. In the Drupal world, it would make sense to use the Drupal-specific function.

The files[] directive is for class autoloading - you don't use it to include files as such, just to make classes in those files available automatically when you need them.

You shouldn't use `module_load_include()` at the top of a module (or any other) file, it should be used only after Drupal has been bootstrapped. From [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7):

> Do not use this function in a global context since it requires Drupal to be fully bootstrapped, use require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/path/file' instead.

Comment: so i can use `require_once` at top of the `.module` file ?

Comment: Absolutely, that's the recommendation from the core developers

Comment: Can we safely use drupal_get_path() (common.inc) in combination with require_once, for getting the path to the module folder? Or is that also only loaded in a full bootstrap?

Comment: @Clive could you help me out here?

Answer (score -1):

The best way for drupal to know you have included [files](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#files) is having it in the `files[]` directive, as Clive says this is perfect for classes, but you can also use it for any files.

Using [`module_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) you can add some loading logic, you can load also files from another module, and for best performance you can load them from within a function or a conditional structure. That way is only loaded when you are using it.

Comment: No, you cannot use `files[]` for any files, since Drupal will use it just to load classes.

Comment: I'm using it now in a drupal 7 module